# Use jq to merge list of dictionaries into one dictionary with keys

Tags: jq

I have a dictionary like:

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "ID": "123abc",
            "Name": "test name",
            "Description": "item 1"
        },
        {
            "ID": "321zyx",
            "Name": "test name two",
            "Description": "item 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to use `jq` to convert this into:

```
{
    "123abc": {
        "Name": "test name",
        "Description": "item 1"
    },
    "321zyx": {
        "Name": "test name two",
        "Description": "item 2"
    }
}
```

Is that possible? If so, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: What did you try to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all `.ID` values are unique, you could use the `INDEX` [function](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#sql-style-operators) (available since jq 1.6) which takes a stream and creates an object, using a given index, `.ID` in this case, as keys:

```bash
jq 'INDEX(.Items[]; .ID)' input.json
```

```json
{
  "123abc": {
    "ID": "123abc",
    "Name": "test name",
    "Description": "item 1"
  },
  "321zyx": {
    "ID": "321zyx",
    "Name": "test name two",
    "Description": "item 2"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wYiIPiXLHvp)

To remove the `.ID` keys from the output, use `del` to update each key:

```bash
jq 'INDEX(.Items[]; .ID) | .[] |= del(.ID)'
```

```json
{
  "123abc": {
    "Name": "test name",
    "Description": "item 1"
  },
  "321zyx": {
    "Name": "test name two",
    "Description": "item 2"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/c7NwiixmAdC)

If you don't have the `INDEX` function, you could adapt from it from [jq's source](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/ce0e788ce28c675808a6bc9a34f8db1199cd7cef/src/builtin.jq#L271C3-L271C63):

```bash
jq 'reduce .Items[] as $i ({}; .[$i.ID|tostring] = $i)' input.json
# or
jq 'reduce .Items[] as $i ({}; .[$i.ID|tostring] = ($i | del(.ID)))' input.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/hqvhnyFfs0W) or
[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/CILvud0kwKz)

Comment: You could also add a `del(.ID)` if OP really doesn't want that ID in the deepest object as shown in his question.

Answer (score 1):

As always, I post a question, and seconds later I determine the answer. (I do not do this on purpose! It's a fairy curse.)

The JSON is in a file, so:

```bash
cat items.json | jq '
    .Items
    | map(select(.ID)
    | {(.ID): . } )
    | add'
```

Which turns into:

```json
{
    "123abc": {
        "ID": "123abc",
        "Name": "test name",
        "Description": "item 1"
    },
    "321zyx": {
        "ID": "321zyx",
        "Name": "test name two",
        "Description": "item 2"
    }
}
```

It keeps the ID as part of the dictionary, but that's acceptable to me.

Comment: `select(.ID)` filters out items that either don't have an `.ID` field, or it has `false` or `null` as its value. If this doesn't occur in your data, you could safely omit it. Also, replace `{(.ID): .})` with `{(.ID): del(.ID)})` if you want to remove the original `.ID` fields.

Comment: Useless use of cat: jq can read files `jq '...' items.json`

Answer (score 0):

```
.Items | map({key: .ID, value: del(.ID)}) | from_entries
```

produces the desired output.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are . Please [edit✏️] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.